# Matching within nested list using in Apache AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age, opencypher

So I have a list of lists as a property. Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('list_test', $$
  CREATE(a: person {nickname: [['thomas', 'tomtom'], ['tom', 'tommy']]})
  RETURN a
$$) as (timothy agtype);
```

I have tried the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('list_test', $$
  MATCH(name)
  UNWIND(name.nickname) as n
  WHERE 'thomas' in UNWIND(n)
  RETURN nnn
$$) as result;
```

But I get syntax error with this.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 2: MATCH(name) UNWIND(name.nickname) as n WHERE 'thomas' in UNW...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using WITH, you can manipulate the output before it is passed on to
> the following query parts. The manipulations can be of the shape
> and/or number of entries in the result set.

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('list_test', $$
    MATCH (name:person)
    UNWIND name.nickname as n
    WITH n WHERE 'thomas' IN n
    RETURN n
$$) as (result agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html), you have to use `agtype` as the type returned by AGE. Also, to return the `nickname` list as individual rows you must use `UNWIND` twice as a command, without the `()`. Finally, you have to use `WITH` clause with `WHERE`clause.

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('list_test', $$
  MATCH(name)
  UNWIND name.nickname as x 
  UNWIND x as n
  WITH n WHERE 'thomas' in n
  RETURN n
$$) as (n agtype);
```

To return:

```
    n     
----------
 "thomas"
 "tomtom"
 "tom"
 "tommy"
(4 rows)
```